# Is Constant Folding a type of Memoization?

Tags: compilers, memoization

I was reading about [Constant Folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) and it sounds very similar to Memoization so I suspect that it indeed is a type of memoization but I've done some searching and can't find a solid answer (in academic papers, etc.) on that.

Is Constant Folding a type of memoization?

Comment: The question seems hard to answer because memoization does not have a strict definition and there are multiple ways to implement constant folding.